# Google script repository with HTTPS?

Tags: jquery, https

I need to load Jquery from google repository [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide).

On a HTTPS enviroment, its possible? I can't test this right now, and need to know. Someone already maked it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

If you look at the URLs they give you, you'll notice that they are *protocol-relative* URLs.
On HTTPS sites, those URLs will be parsed as HTTPS.

Comment: So i don't need to change http or https? just call //ajax.googleapis... ?

Comment: This won't work correctly in all browsers though. But basically yes

Comment: @Yeronimo why not? What browser you know it doesn't work? IE8?

Comment: Well it will work for the script tag, so no issue there, but when protocol-relative urls get used in @imports of CSS or link tags, then IE6, 7 and 8 will break. Also this won't work with canonical urls, as you might be mixing protocols at this point. I read a good aticle on this a few months back. I will try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just use the http(s) you need:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL `//host/...` looks a bit odd but it's a valid relative URL: It's relative to the protocol that was used to load the rest of the document.

This nifty trick allows a HTML page to load other resources with the same protocol that was used to load itself without any JavaScript or other magic.

It's often used for pages that might be delivered with either HTTP or HTTPS. By using a protocol relative URL, the browser will not leave the security of HTTPS to load additional resources and it works with static code.

Comment: I can do this with my local scripts? Or i'll need to treat this "issue" on htaccess or something?

Comment: It's a feature built into the web browser: If you omit part of the URL, the browser will fill it in with parts from the parent URL. For scripts, the parent URL is the one of the document. The HTTP server will never notice that this happens. Servers always get absolute URLs.

Comment: @Guerra: Note that this won't work with `file://` URLs, since it will try to load `file://ajax.googleapis.com/...`, which does not exist.